# css media query. cannot center a flex box for mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
***Dear all,
```

for a signup form, i tried to apply media queries rules in order that this flexbox form will appears center and fit the screeen. i have tried different option but i cannot find the solution.
can anyone help please?[image: here is copy of the screen]``
i leave as well my git repository.[github project](https://github.com/beautythieves/P7-groupomania)***
how can i make the login form apprearing in center and shrink in case of the screen is small?

```css
<style lang="css" scoped>
.grp-login__grandParentContainer{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#d7ffd9;
    font-size:25px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    
}
.grp-login__parentContainer {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#eaffd7;
    background-image: url('~@/assets/logosansnom.png');
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
.grp-login__form {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 50px;
    }

    
.grp-login__form__login__button {
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background:  red;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.grp-login__form__login__button:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.grp-login__form__login__button:active {
    color: red;
}

.grp-login__form__login__button:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.grp-login__form__login__button:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.grp-login__form__login__button:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
  .grp-login__grandParentContainer {
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#d7ffd9;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:  50px;
    width: 60%;
  }
  .grp-login__parentContainer{
    text-align:center;
  }
  
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="grp-login__grandParentContainer">
        <div class="grp-login__parentContainer">
            <form class="grp-login__form">
                <div class="grp-login__form__email">
                    <label class="">Email </label>
                    <input v-model="email" type="email" class="">
                </div>
                <div class="grp-login__form__password">
                    <label class="">Mot de passe </label>
                    <input v-model="password" type="password" class="">
                </div>
                <div class="grp-login__form__login">
                <button @click= "goLogin" type= "button" class="grp-login__form__login__button">Login</button>
                </div>
               
            </form>
            <div v-if="isError">Erreur de connexion</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want the login form be center in the small screen or on all screen ?

Comment: Make the `grandParentContainer` 100% width (full screen width) with **centered content** (flex, justify-content:center). Apply media queries for width to `parentContainer`. No matter how small the login box will be, it'll be always centered by the grandparent.

Comment: sorry but it daes not work (or maybe i did not do it properly). can you explain step by step or correct the code liens please? thank you for your precious help!